# How to call perl file every minute from batch file

Tags: filesystems, batch, batch-file, perl, batch-rename

I have written a perl script which i try to call every 1 minute from a batch file.

There is no error but it do not call it every 1 minute. It just pop command prompt when clicked once on .bat file. My code to do is this: (batchTestShe.bat) the ccc.pl and batchTestShe.bat are in same folde and ccc.pl runs only once i click on batchTestShe.bat but never repeats execution.

```
schtasks /create /tn "batch Script" /tr C:\shekhar_Axestrack_Intern\WindowCreation\batchTestShe.bat /sc minute /mo 1 
perl C:\shekhar_Axestrack_Intern\WindowCreation\ccc.pl
```

I can see on taskschd.msc it show it's nect execution next minute but do not pop up command prompt next minute. WHY any idea ?

And please note that i also do not want something message at prompt like . This file already exist do you wanna rename it Y/N ?  I want just running it every minute non stopingly.

Comment: Why not pause your perl script for a minute and loop?

Comment: What are the contents of finals.bat?

Comment: @Foosh that was batchTestShe.bat sorry my mistake (the file itself)

Comment: @LPChip COULD YOU PLeae give me the basic body of repeating that way every minute ?

Comment: My perl is rusty. It has been years ago since I programmed in it. But I'm pretty sure google knows the answer.

Comment: Looks like you're just spamming the scheduler the way you have it setup, never giving you a chance to repeat.  I would remove that line from the batch file and run that line manually once on the command prompt (since that should tell it to run every minute).  In your perl script, I would have it write the date and time to a log file when it starts so you can validate that it's running.

Comment: @Foosh sorry still not able to understand what you explained .. Any practical example please  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all your batch script does is call the Perl script every 60 seconds, then you can put the logic in your Perl script itself and reduce some clutter.

```
#!perl

while(1){

...

Your code here

...

sleep(60);
}
```

If you need more advanced scheduling you can even use a module like https://metacpan.org/pod/EV::Cron to enable Cron-ish job scheduling in your system.

Answer (score 0):

You have a batch file that is re-creating the same scheduled task over and over. You could avoid creating the scheduled task and just make this your batch file:

```
:START
    perl C:\shekhar_Axestrack_Intern\WindowCreation\ccc.pl
    timeout /t 60
goto :START
```

Or, wrap your perl script in a while loop to run every 60 seconds:

```
while (1) {
    sleep 60;
    your ccc.pl code goes here;
}
```

Those solutions will result in drift since they take (60 seconds + script execution time) to run. If you need it to run exactly every 60 seconds, stick with the task scheduler approach, but try launching your perl script directly rather than through a batch file. Also make sure your script doesn't take longer than 60 seconds to run or you could end up with multiple instances running in parallel.

```
schtasks /create /tn "run ccc.pl once a minute" /tr "perl C:\shekhar_Axestrack_Intern\WindowCreation\ccc.pl" /sc minute /mo 1
```